# MVC: System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'Delete' was not found on controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Html helper method that calls a Delete method on my controller.

```
public static MvcHtmlString DeleteEmployeeOtherLeave(this HtmlHelper html, string linkText, Leave _leave)
{
    return html.RouteLink(linkText, "Default",
        new { _employeeOtherLeaveId = _leave.LeaveId, action = "Delete" },
        new { onclick = "$.post(this.href); return false;" });
}
```

On my controller I have;

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Delete)]
public ActionResult Delete(int _employeeOtherLeaveId)
{
    EmployeeOtherLeaf.Delete(_employeeOtherLeaveId);

    return RedirectToAction("Payroll");
}
```

But I get this runtime error message;

```
    System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'Delete' was not found on controller
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible that your action isn't being invoked by an HTTP request that is sending the correct "DELETE" verb in this case.  Try updating your AcceptVerbs attribute to take a POST instead.

Answer (score 3):

You are sending a POST request whereas your controller action expects a DELETE verb. So:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DeleteEmployeeOtherLeave(this HtmlHelper html, string linkText, Leave _leave)
{
    return html.RouteLink(linkText, "Default",
        new { _employeeOtherLeaveId = _leave.LeaveId, action = "Delete" },
        new { onclick = "$.ajax({url: this.href, type: 'DELETE'}); return false;" });
}
```

Comment: I have had problems with this solution when testing in IE. I asked on the MVC forum and they said I should post POST instead. See http://forums.asp.net/t/1658625.aspx/1?The+DELETE+Http+works+in+FF+but+not+in+IE. Now I get this error again I am back to square one. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

or you can also change your verb in your form method attribute to delete either method should work