# MVC: I delete a row from my grid, but my page does not refresh

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a Html.Helper that I use to delete rows from my grid.
It calls the following method on my controller;

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Delete)]
    public ActionResult Delete(int _employeeOtherLeaveId)
    {
        EmployeeOtherLeaf.Delete(_employeeOtherLeaveId);
        return RedirectToAction("Payroll");
    }
```

This calls the GET method on my controller which I would expect to refresh the view of my grid, but it doesn't. When I manually refresh I see the row has in fact been deleted. Why is this?

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Payroll()
{
    if ((SessionObjects.PeriodStartDate > DateTime.MinValue) && (SessionObjects.PeriodEndDate > DateTime.MinValue))
        if (SessionObjects.PayrollSelectedEmployeeId == 0)
            return View(new PayrollViewModel()
                {
                    PeriodStartDate = SessionObjects.PeriodStartDate,
                    PeriodEndDate = SessionObjects.PeriodEndDate
                });
        else
            return View(new PayrollViewModel(
                SessionObjects.PeriodStartDate,
                SessionObjects.PeriodEndDate,
                SessionObjects.PayrollSelectedEmployeeId
                ));

    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will depend how you are calling the `DELETE` action. Judging from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900615/mvc-system-web-httpexception-a-public-action-method-delete-was-not-found-on-c) and the [answer you accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4900615/mvc-system-web-httpexception-a-public-action-method-delete-was-not-found-on-c/4900626#4900626) I suppose that you are doing the following:

```
onclick="$.ajax({url: this.href, type: 'DELETE'}); return false;"
```

which obviously is insufficient as you are sending the AJAX request to delete but you aren't handling the `success` event to update the DOM. So you might need to do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: this.href, 
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
        // update some DOM element with the result returned by the
        // server. So supposing that you have some <div id="someContainer">
        // that will contain the part of the DOM you want updated:
        $('#someContainer').html(result);
    }
}); 
return false;
```

Now obviously stuffing all this javascript inside the HTML as you were using your custom helper is ugly. Personally I would use unobtrusive javascript. I would have my helper generate a normal anchor with a class and then in a completely separate javascript file I would AJAXify this link:

```
$(function() {
    // AJAXify the anchor with the delete class that would
    // be generated by your custom helper
    $('.delete').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href, 
            type: 'DELETE',
            success: function(result) {
                // update some DOM element with the result returned by the
                // server. So supposing that you have some <div id="someContainer">
                // that will contain the part of the DOM you want updated:
                $('#someContainer').html(result);
            }
        }); 
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: What would I do without you Darin? Thank you.

Comment: I noticed that you edited your answer, and I am always interested in good technique so I did what you suggest. But now I get the error message; System.Web.HttpException: A public action method 'Delete' was not found on controller 'SHP.Controllers.PayrollController'. But I haven't changed this method on the controller, it is public. What could be happening?

Comment: @arame3333, that's weird. If you are getting this error message and your action is decorated with the `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Delete)]` attribute it means that the request which is sent to this action was not using the DELETE verb. This could happen if you have a javascript error and your AJAX call doesn't work correctly and the browser simply ends up following the link with a GET request.

Comment: I found in Firebug that this.href is not defined

Comment: Having said that I then hardcoded the url I wanted to navigate to, and I still had the same error.